Can we choose a function as follows?
Let $\Omega$ be a bounded smooth open set of $\mathbb R^N$.
For any such $\Omega$, can we choose a function $f \in C^2(\overline \Omega)$ satisfying the following conditions?

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial n} = 1$ on $\partial \Omega$, where $n$ is the unit outward normal to $\Omega$.
$f = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$.
$f > 0$ in $\Omega$.

I think that we cannot choose such $f$ because Condition 1 implies that $f$ is decreasing in the direction of $-n$ and then, with Condition 2, $f$ must be negative in $\Omega$ near $\partial \Omega$.
Is that right?

Yes, your reasoning is correct.
The function $f$ you described cannot exist due to the contradiction between the conditions.
Condition 1, $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial n} = 1$ on $\partial \Omega$, implies that $f$ is increasing in the direction of the outward normal $n$. This means that as you move outwards from the boundary of $\Omega$, $f$ should increase.
However, Condition 2 states that $f = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$. This means that $f$ is zero at the boundary of $\Omega$.
Given these two conditions, it would imply that $f$ must be negative somewhere in $\Omega$ near $\partial \Omega$, contradicting Condition 3 which states that $f > 0$ in $\Omega$.
So, you are correct that such a function $f$ cannot exist.
